# Create GeoJSON after processing.runalg('qgis:clip', ...)

Tags: qgis, gdal, pyqgis

I have the following problem:
I have two vector layers, foobar and clipLayer. About the python console I call the following command:

`processing.runalg ('qgis:clip', 'foobar', 'clipLayer', None)`

As a result, I get the temporary path to a Shp-file. That is so far correct. But I need the result not as a Shp-file but in a GeoJSON format.

How can I convert the shapefile to the GeoJSON format?
There is a convert function within the GDAL tools.

`processing.runalg('gdalogr:convertformat', input_layer, format, options, output_layer)`

As a result, I get the path to a file .shp.geojson. but I want to get a GeoJSON string as a result.

Why do I need this?
Within a plugin the clip function is used. The result must be further processed as a Qgsfeature. In this case I can not use a shp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using something like the following which was tested in the **Python console** where you can call the output of the `clip` algorithm as an input to the `convertformat` algorithm:

```
clip_layer= processing.runalg("qgis:clip", layer2, layer1, None)
processing.runandload('gdalogr:convertformat', clip_layer["OUTPUT"], 1, "", None)
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @eftas - Most welcome but I would suggest you post your _Update_ as an **answer** instead of editing it into the question =)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Sometimes the solution is simpler than you think. First, I proceed as described by Joseph. After carrying out the converter function I get a .geojson file. This can be further processed as follows:

```
json.load(open(pathGeoJSON))
```

From the generated JSON file the coordinates can be extracted and a QgsFeature generated.